# Reset style for input[type="submit"] to match input[type="text"]

Tags: css

I am trying to get the style of input 'submit' match the input 'text', as in the defaults the submit gets a little under the text input.

https://jsfiddle.net/2wy8k06v/3/

I tried to reset the borders and margins but with no effect :

```
input[type="text"], input[type="url"] {

            border-radius: 0px;
}
input[type="submit"] {

            border-radius: 0px;
            margin: 0;
            height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Lose the quotation marks mate.... it’ll work

Comment: what will work?

Comment: The css youve put up.